# Is there a command library interface for LVM?

Tags: lvm

I am developing a code module which identifies all the partitions in the linux machine.
I also need to figure out if any of the partitions are using LVM. If LVM is used, then i should create snapshot and return the snapshot mounted volume names.

For all these things, should i use LVM commands and parse the output ? Or is there a library from LVM which can provide all the information ?

Answer (score 0):

lvm support c api.
see: https://git.fedorahosted.org/cgit/lvm2.git/tree/liblvm/lvm2app.h

Or you could use command "blkid" to see whether a block device is a physical volume.